# How to write cooerctly an axios function with passed paraethers?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, post, axios

I'm tryin g to make a POST request axios with a somekind of data inside the method. But the code isn't glooming. I think Im inserting the lines of code into a wrong place, could you correct the place of the lines, please?

```js
methods: {
    searchDrafts(searchData) {
      if (searchData) {
        return this.array.hello
      } else {
        return this.array
      }
      axios({                    // code from this place isn't lighted
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/drafts/search',
      })
        .then(res => {
          success = true
        })
        .catch(error => {
          error = console.log('post request error')
        })
    },
  },
```

Comment: Look at the code *just before* the `axios` call.  You're *returning from the function*.  Code after a `return` statement is unreachable.

Comment: What did you mean by "glooming" or "lighted"?

Comment: I meant highlighting )

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks, I guess whan I remove the return nothing really changes, needs some refactoring ))